# JavaScript Assigning Variables

Tags: javascript, oop

```
var example = {

    something: 'test',

    test: function() {
        this.something = 'blah';
    }

}

example.test();
```

Why doesn't 'test' get updated with 'blah' in this case?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/LVwJh/

Comment: For me too (Chromium). Just to be sure: 'something' gets updated. 'test' is your function!

Comment: Do you mean `this[something] = 'blah';`? That would set the property `example.test` to `'blah'`.

Comment: @Cory: `something` is not defined, at least in the posted code. It would have been `this[this.something]`, but I really don't think that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: Since your code works fine, it does not seem you have a problem ;)

Comment: Sorry, typo. Definitely meant `this[this.something]`.

Comment: @jbabey: The jsfiddle code works for me too. In fact, when I tried with console.log, it worked for my code. However, using the console and trying to do `example.something` returns 'test' instead of 'blah'.

Comment: You must be doing something which we don't know about. Not much we can do for you then. The code you posted is fine.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine. If you expect that example.test() returns the new value try this:

```
var example = {

    something: 'test',

    test: function() {
        this.something = 'blah';
        return this.something;
    }

}

example.test();
// output: "blah"
```